# compare two different length lists of dictionaries in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I want to compare below dictionaries. Name key in the dictionary is common in both dictionaries.
If Name matched in both the dictionaries, i wanted to do some other stuff with the data.

```
PerfData = [
            {'Name': 'abc', 'Type': 'Ex1', 'Access': 'N1', 'perfStatus':'Latest Perf', 'Comments': '07/12/2017  S/W Version'},
            {'Name': 'xyz', 'Type': 'Ex1', 'Access': 'N2', 'perfStatus':'Latest Perf', 'Comments': '11/12/2017  S/W Version upgrade failed'},
            {'Name': 'efg', 'Type': 'Cust1', 'Access': 'A1', 'perfStatus':'Old Perf', 'Comments': '11/10/2017  S/W Version upgrade failed, test data is active'}
        ]

 beatData = [
            {'Name': 'efg', 'Status': 'Latest', 'rcvd-timestamp': '1516756202.632'},
            {'Name': 'abc', 'Status': 'Latest', 'rcvd-timestamp': '1516756202.896'}
            ]
```

Thanks
Rajeev

Comment: What have you tried? Please see [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes, you can compare two dictionaries by matching keys.

Comment: This is just sample data, i wanted to iterate with two separate dictionaries and if **Name** in both the dictionaries is common then perform some auto-action or assign values to new variables from the remaining keys. Looping does take lots of time to perform, is there any better way to do efficiently?

Comment: @RajeevK Show us an example of what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = [{'name': 'abc'}, {'name': 'xyz'}]
k = [{'name': 'a'}, {'name': 'abc'}]
[i['name'] for i in l for f in k if i['name'] == f['name']]
```

Hope above logic work for you.

Comment: Sorry, it may be silly question, code is working with no error, however i was trying to print compared values, but it's stating "i" is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided didn't assign the result to any variable. If you want to print it, add the following would work:

```
result = [i['name'] for i in l for f in k if i['name'] == f['name']]
print(result)
```